# router link path seems to be wrong

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I created a .net core class in the back end and I am passing the data to angular 8 application. The angular project is also part of the Visual studio application. I can compile both the angular and visual studio project with no issues. when I run my application, I see fetch-project in my navigation bar and nothing happened when I click on it. Below is the structure of my angular application. 
   [image]

and below is the code in my nav-menu-component.html.

```
 <div class='navbar-collapse collapse' [ngClass]='{ "in": isExpanded }'>
          <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>

              <li [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]'>
                  <a [routerLink]='["/fetch-project"]' (click)='collapse()'>
                      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></span> Fetch Project
                  </a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

Nothing happens when I click on the fetch-project button. I thought my routerlink is wrong, but routerlink seems to be correct because fetch-project lies in the same directory as fetch-project. Below is the code for my fetch-project.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectDetailService } from '../services/projectdetail.service';
import { AllItProject } from '../../Models/allitproject';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fetch-project',
  templateUrl: './fetch-project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fetch-project.component.css']
})
export class FetchProjectComponent {

  public projectList: AllItProject[];

  constructor(private _projectService: ProjectDetailService) {
    this.getProjectDetails();
  }

  getProjectDetails() {
    this._projectService.getProjectDetails().subscribe(
      (data: AllItProject[]) => this.projectList = data
    );
  }

  delete(projectID) {
    const ans = confirm('Do you want to delete this project with Id: ' + projectID);
    if (ans) {
      this._projectService.deleteProject(projectID).subscribe(() => {
        this.getProjectDetails();
      }, error => console.error(error));
    }
  }
}
```

Below is my code for app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';

import { FetchProjectComponent } from './fetch-project/fetch-project.component';
import { AddProjectComponent } from './add-project/add-project.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    FetchProjectComponent,
    AddProjectComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([

      { path: 'fetch-project', component: FetchProjectComponent },
      { path: 'register-project', component: AddProjectComponent },
      { path: 'project/edit/:id', component: AddProjectComponent },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and below is the code for projectDetail.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AllItProject } from '../../models/allitproject';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectDetailService {

  myAppUrl = '';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.myAppUrl = baseUrl;
  }

  getProjectDetails() {
    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/Index').pipe(map(
      response => {
        return response;
      }));
  }

  getAppDevList() {
    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/GetAppDevList')
      .pipe(map(
        response => {
          return response;
        }));
  }

  getBsaList() {
    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/GetBsaList')
      .pipe(map(
        response => {
          return response;
        }));
  }

  getProjectSection() {
    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/GetProjectSection')
      .pipe(map(
        response => {
          return response;
        }));
  }


  getProjectStatus() {
    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/GetProjectStatus')
      .pipe(map(
        response => {
          return response;
        }));
  }

  getAcrDivison() {
    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/GetAcrDivison')
      .pipe(map(
        response => {
          return response;
        }));
  }

  getProjectSubType() {
    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/GetProjectSubType')
      .pipe(map(
        response => {
          return response;
        }));
  }
  getProjectType() {
    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/GetProjectTypes')
      .pipe(map(
        response => {
          return response;
        }));
  }


  getExecutiveSponsor() {
    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/GetExecutiveSponsor')
      .pipe(map(
        response => {
          return response;
        }));
  }



  getProjectById(id: number) {
    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/Details/' + id)
      .pipe(map(
        response => {
          return response;
        }));
  }

  saveProject(project: AllItProject) {
    return this._http.post(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/Create', project)
      .pipe(map(
        response => {
          return response;
        }));
  }

  updateProject(project: AllItProject) {
    return this._http.put(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsList/Edit', project)
      .pipe(map(
        response => {
          return response;
        }));
  }

  deleteProject(id: number) {
    return this._http.delete(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsList/Delete/' + id)
      .pipe(map(
        response => {
          return response;
        }));
  }

}
```

Below is the image of the screen of what I get.

[image]
any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you created a router module?? - becasue routerLink will only work for angular routing

Comment: Where are your routes defined? If they're in `app.module.ts` please show that code

Comment: I pasted my code for app.module.ts

Comment: Do you have errors in browser using F12 development tools?Do you just need to redirect to `/fetch-project`?

Comment: I just need to redirect to /fetch-project. when I am clicking on fetch-project, nothing is happening. I am very new to angular. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I also added the picture of the screen that I am getting when I run this application.  any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to configure route path for `FetchProjectComponent`  in `RouterModule.forRoot` in `app.module.ts`,refer to my correct configuration code below.

app.module.ts:

```
//other imports
import { FetchProjectComponent } from './fetch-project/fetch-project.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  NavMenuComponent,
  HomeComponent,
  CounterComponent,
  FetchDataComponent,
  FetchProjectComponent
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-project', component: FetchProjectComponent },
    ])
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```